# Classic theme not working after custom theme was deployed

Tags: liferay, liferay-6, liferay-theme

We are facing a strange issue on our environment. We deployed our custom theme which was working fine with tomcat on our `Problem Environment` and it started throwing the following error for pages with Classic Theme:

```
19:21:31,020 WARN  [http-bio-8080-exec-3][code_jsp:?] {code="404", msg="/html/themes/classic/css/compass"}
```

We undeployed our custom theme, we replaced the ROOT.war, we even replaced the whole server with a clean install but the same error.

And when I check with [firebug](/questions/tagged/firebug) on firefox I see that the `custom.css` and other css files are not loaded for the pages and hence the styles are not applied. I can see `aui.css` and `main.css` but not the other CSS files which I can see on my local.

I found this issue [LPS-46864](https://issues.liferay.com/browse/LPS-46864) in which the error log is similar, but the cause is different. We don't have any hook deployed only our custom theme and some independent plugin portlets.

**Problem Environment**: Liferay 6.2 EE Jboss Bundle on CentOS 6.2

Any pointers as to what might be wrong would help.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I exactly don't know what solved it but here is what I did:

1. Replaced the `ROOT.war` with a fresh installation. (I had done this previously).
2. Removed jboss's `tmp` folder. (I had also done this before)
3. Removed `*.tmp` files and `liferay` folder from `/tmp/` folder of linux.
4. Removed other different previous liferay installations (the servers were already not running just the folders were there)
5. Restarted the server

Thats all. This is one of those rare kind of issues, but still might help somebody.